# Vscode Do a custom command when running languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to run moonscript files (or other languages) in a certain workspace with the "Run code" shortcut of vscode (which shows `code not supported or defined` for the moment), but I don't understand which file I have to edit in order to do that (settings.json?). I've searched on the Vscode documentation, but can't find it.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run the code? [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)? Using the [debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)? Through an extension?

Comment: I'm using Code Runner. Should I use Tasks instead?